# "Ineligible value used in/as type annotation" error with Flow

Tags: flowtype

I have a JS file:

```
// @flow
import type SomeType from './types';

export class MyClass extends React.Component {
  props: {
    someProp: Array<SomeType>
  };
}
```

In types.js:

```
// @flow
export type SomeType = {
  someKey: number
}
```

Running `flow` gives me the following error on `Array<SomeType>`:

```
exports. Ineligible value used in/as type annotation (did you forget 'typeof'?)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is me being an ES6 noob. The fix is in how the type is imported. It should be:

```
import type {SomeType} from './types';
```